# android - ViewPager is bugging on the galaxy S2

Tags: android, galaxy, android-viewpager

I wanted to use the ViewPager included in the compatibility library (revision 6).
So i created an Activity where each page displays text contained in a textview.
There are about 40 pages.

When i scroll, there is a bug only when is install the app on my galaxy S2. When scrolling some pages (about 25 pages, or sometimes when i scroll from page 1 to 30 and then trying to go from page 30 to 1), the activity stops but without displaying any error in the logcat.

I tried the same app, in 3 others devices (nexus one, Xperia X10, motorola xoom) and everything works very well!!

Do somebody faces the same problem? Is there any solution?

**EDIT**: if i add (assuming pager is an instance of ViewPager)

```
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(PAGE_NUMBER);
```

everything works well, but unfortunately the more the pages you have, the more it takes memory...
Hoping somebody will have another solution.